# Accessing label from child control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a control `Orders.ascx` in this control I have a reference to another control `Grid.ascx` something like this:

In my `Orders.ascx` I have :

```
   <asp:Label id="warnings" runat="server" />
   <uc:Grids id="uxGrid" runat="server/>
```

Now in the grid `( Grids.ascx )` I have a drop down control that has the quantities with a event handler method for on index change, when a different quantity is chosen in a row, it posts back and updates the price depending on the quantity. I need for each time it posts back to add a message to the label warnings in `Orders.ascx`, but my problem is that this label is in the parent control. I tried using FindControl and it DOES find it and I can set the text but it never updates the warnings label.

How can I update that label text from the drop down's on index change control?. It seems that it doesnt inject everytime i select the quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest, cleanest way would be to use an event.

1. Create an event argument class, derived from EventArgs, that includes a property for the data you want to pass:

   ```
    public class PriceChangeEventArgs: EventArgs
    {
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. Set up an event in the UserControl:

   ```
    public event EventHandler<PriceChangeEventArgs> PriceChanged;
   ```
3. Raise the event when capturing the change in the drop down list index:

   ```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object source, EventArg e)
    {
        PriceChangeEventArgs args = new PriceChangeEventArgs();
        args.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
        PriceChanged(this, args);
    }
   ```
4. Handle the event in the parent control page or control:

   ```
   UserControl1.PriceChanged += new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(page_PriceChanged);

   protected void page_PriceChanged(object source, MyEventArgs e)
   {
       Label1.Text = e.Price.ToString("C");
   }
   ```

This way, you haven't tied your user control in to your page: you can still use the user control other places, and the page doesn't need to know how the user control works, other than that it raises an event.

ETA:  Added an important step I omitted:  *actually raising the event!*

Comment: Thank you!, where would be the best suitable place to add UserControl1.PriceChanged += new EventHandler<MyEventArgs>(page_PriceChanged); ? on the Load section?

Comment: @user710502  Assuming the user control is declared in the markup of the parent (as opposed to being added dynamically), that should work.  You could also specify the handler in the tag:  `<uc:Grids id="uxGrid" runat="server" PriceChanged="page_PriceChanged" />`  I'm pretty sure that would also work.