# How to switch among tabs with the Ajax Control Toolkit TabContainer?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have 3 ascx controls loaded in one aspx file as a tabbed manner. I have one button in first ascx control. If the button is clicked then I have to move to next tab. How to move to next tab?

Comment: What control are you using? MutliView? Telerik? Ajax Toolkit? Bespoke?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you or your organization wrote the 3 ascx controls?

You're going to have to alert the parent of the tabbed control (the page?) that a child of the tabbed control (the ascx control) has requested that the tab control progress to another tab.

The simplest, least coupled way I know how to do this is with a custom event.  The steps would be as follows:

1. Implement an event in your ascx control that is raised when the button in your ascx control is clicked.  There's an example of this in [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719337/accessing-label-from-child-control/15719444#15719444).

   Since you're using Visual Basic, the syntax for the fourth step will be different.  I describe this in the next step, below.
2. Set up a handler for that event in the page.  (This is Step 4 in the example I linked to.)

   The simplest way to associate the handler with the user control is in the markup:

   ```
   <uc:MyUserControl TabChangeRequested="MyUserControl_TabChangeRequested" 
     runat="server" id="userControl1" />
   ```

   This example assumes that `MyUserControl_TabChangeRequested` is a public or protected method of your page.

   If this doesn't work, you can do the association programmatically.  How you do this depends on whether the user control is visible to the page itself, or is a child of the tab control. If the user control is a child of the page, you can use this code (in Page_Load):

   ```
   AddHandler userControl1.TabChangeRequested, AddressOf MyUserControl_TabChangeRequested
   ```

   It's a very different syntax to that of C#, which can make examples confusing.

   If the user control is a child of the tab control rather than being declared at the page control, you need to first get a reference to the user control from within the control collection of the specific tab:

   ```
      Dim uc as MyUserControl = TabControl1.Tabs(0).FindControl("userControl1")
      AddHandler uc.TabChangeRequested, AddressOf MyUserControl_TabChangeRequested
   ```

   Depending on the tab control and how it was written, you might need to look in the tab control's own children rather than the tab's.  The first line of the previous example would look like this:

   ```
     Dim uc as MyUserControl = TabControl1.FindControl("userControl1")
   ```
3. In your handler, do whatever you need to do to change to the next tab.

Comment: Thanks Ann. I am really struck to convert that 4 th point in to VB.net. Could you please help

Comment: @Gansun  I'll do my best.  The syntax is totally different, you're right.

Comment: @Gansun  I've expanded my answer to include some more examples and explanations.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Ann. Its working fine. My only problem is instead calling the "TabContainer1.ActiveTab = TabContainer1.Tabs(1)" I would like click the tab automatically.

Comment: You mean, simulate a client-side click? That would be a javascript (possibly jQuery) solution.  Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks. I did it using javascript.